# Is there an application that can see hand gestures to turn on the screen and scroll?

Tags: ios

While I am cooking with dirty and wet hands, I want to see the recipe on my smartphone without dirtying it.

How may I turn on the display and scroll without touching the phone?

Is there an application that can see hand gestures to turn on the screen and scroll?

Comment: Is jailbreak an option ?

Comment: jailbreak is an option, but I would like to not have to jailbreak

Comment: No "normal" can do it.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be an 'app for that' but you can do what I see in many Chinese take-out places - put some cling plastic wrap over the screen like they do with the keys of the cash-registers. OtterBox also makes cases with screen protectors. Cling wrap is far less expensive, though.